# getting "antiword" error while converting .doc documents to .txt

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, antiword

I have this below code which I'm using to convert word documents into txt. Code is good for .docx documents but for .doc below code is working okay in one system but is giving "antiword" error when I'm running this code on another system. "Both are windows 11 systems"

```
def doc2txt(input_report_path, final_report_path):
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_report_path)[1]

    try:
        if file_extension.lower() == ".docx":
            # Extract text from .docx file using python-docx
            doc = Document(input_report_path)
            paragraphs = [paragraph.text for paragraph in doc.paragraphs]
            text = "\n".join(paragraphs)
        elif file_extension.lower() == ".doc":
            # Extract text from .doc file using textract
            text = textract.process(input_report_path, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')

        with open(final_report_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
            txt_file.write(text)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error converting {input_report_path}: {e}")
```

Attaching error screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Did you install antiword on the other system?  `textract` doesn't do that for you.

Comment: Yes, I did still issue not fixed. Interesting thing is that in the system where this code is working there is no antiword installed. I do not understand this.

Comment: Perhaps you have to tell it where antiword is installed.  Textract uses antiword for .doc documents, so if those worked, you must have it.